# c3 Charts tooltip doesn't move

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I've been trying to get graphing working, all the data seems to be graphing, however the tooltip doesn't move from the far right. This of course is a issue since I cannot then mouse over specific points to see the data.

Here is a JS fiddle example of what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/kp7eyf8o/6/

**NOTE:** for some reason the stack overflow JSfiddle gives me an error, but the URL should show my issue.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#test',
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
      ['x', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-02', '2016-03-03', '2016-04-04', '2016-05-05', '2016-06-06', '2016-07-07', '2016-08-08', '2016-09-09', '2016-10-10', '2016-11-11', '2016-12-12'],
      ['2016 Actual', 12873666.64, 15976835.94, 19232540.28, 23649495.4, 26338636.36, 29496799.84, 43801703.66, 4263924.64, 5788580.3, ],
      ['2016 Projected', 3916752.11, 4626643.23, 5146264.25, 6148854.32, 6640724.57, 7409783.48, 8263054.46, 8488001.54, 8837809.1, 9068047.68, 9402019.15, 9513505.72, ],
      ['2015 Actual', 3256870.0, 3825580.0, 4394290.0, 5550000.0, 6044000.0, 7100000.0, 7700000.0, 8154000.0, 8860000.0, 9200000.0, 9500000.0, 9600328.45, ]
    ],
    colors: {
      '2016 Actual': '#2cd554',
      '2016 Projected': '#1bc4fc',
      '2015 Actual': '#fdaf5a'
    }
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      tick: {
        culling: false,
        format: '%b'
      }
    },
    y: {
      tick: {
        format: d3.format("$,.2f")
      }
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.12/d3.min.js"></script>


<div id="test"></div>
```

I saw someone mention using 'xs: {x .... y....} but I wasn't able to get that working. I need the X axis to be dates (hard coded right now but in my app I'm using dates associated with one dataset I'm looping through), and the Y axis to be $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C3 tooltips seem to break when data arrays of different lengths are entered into the columns. You can try putting null values into the shorter array so that the tooltip can move properly. 
JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stancheta/7zgny2yd/

```
['2016 Actual', 12873666.64, 15976835.94, 19232540.28, 23649495.4, 26338636.36, 29496799.84, 43801703.66, 4263924.64, 5788580.3, null, null, null],
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! So if I'm using 3 datasets, it's best to somehow determine which is the longest, and then make the other 2 loop through all their data and then return null to even in it out?

Comment: As long as the data sets turn out the same size, it'll be fine :) . I was also looking through the C3 repository and noticed that there was an open pull request for this exact problem, so maybe in a future version, this might become a non-issue.

Comment: Thanks, you've been incredibly helpful.